# Delaying injection of a service until a promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to register a service (or factory, provider, or whatever I have to use) that will not be injected until a particular promise is resolved? So something like:

```
let defer = $q.defer();
function myService() {
   someOtherService.getAsyncStuff().then(result => {
      this.data = result;
      defer.resolve();
   });
}

angular.functionIAmLookingFor("myService", myService, defer.promise);
```

So when some controller/service/whatever has myService injected into their constructor, they can access `myService.data` synchronously and it is guaranteed to be defined?

Comment: You're swimming against the current here.

Comment: That's what route resolvers are for, even if your app doesn't need a router for anything else.